# Is there a non-random variable with Borel set preimage?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, borel-sets

Is there a non-random variable function ξ : Ω → R, for which the following statement is true?

$\forall x ∈ R$ $ξ^{-1}(x) = \{ω| ξ(ω) = x\} \in \mathfrak B(Ω) $

I know that this is true for functions which suit "[random variable function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variable#Functions_of_random_variables#Measure-theoretic%20definition)" definition, but are there any functions which are not "random variable", but fit this rule?

Comment: There are plenty of non-measurable functions which are injective...

Comment: @NateEldredge so does this rule equal "function should be injective"?

Comment: No, injectivity is sufficient but certainly not necessary.  For instance any finite-to-one or countable-to-one function will also work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})=([0,1],\mathcal{B}_{[0,1]})$ and $\xi(\omega)=\omega+2\cdot1_N(\omega)$, where $N\subset [0,1]$ is a non-measurable set. Then for each $x\in \mathbb{R}$, $\xi^{-1}(\{x\})$ is either empty or a singleton so that $\xi^{-1}(\{x\})\in \mathcal{B}_{[0,1]}$. However, $\xi^{-1}([2,3])=N\notin \mathcal{B}_{[0,1]}$.

Comment: What does $1_N(\omega)$ mean?

Comment: @michaeluskov It's the indicator of $N$, i.e. $1_N(\omega)=1$ if $\omega\in N$ and $0$ otherwise.

Comment: As I understood, this function's preimage is not Borel on [2,3], but I need function with inverse function with result which is always Borel set. And it shouldn't be "random value function"

Comment: @michaeluskov In the question you explicitly asked about pre-images of a certain form. Namely, $\xi^{-1}(\{x\})$.

Comment: It is easy to construct an example in which $\xi^{-1}(B)\in \mathcal{B}_{[0,1]}$ for any Borel set $B$ and yet $\xi$ is not a random variable. Just take $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})=([0,1], \sigma([0,1/2]))$ and $\xi(\omega)=\omega$.